# Practical usage of the T3 File Service

Tags: java, weblogic

In the BEA WLS console, it's possible to define "T3 File Service". After googling about it, I was unable any practical info. Is it something useful ?

EDIT:

Deprecated since 6.1 ... a complete overview [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs45/classdocs/API_file.html)  , it's sad that no real alternative is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The WebLogic file T3 service lets you provide high-speed, client-side access to native operating system files on the server.*

Some people used it (with weblogic 6.1) to upload file attachments to an application in a cluster (in a C/S context I guess). Whether this was actually a good use case is another story.

Anyhow, the File Service has been deprecated in Weblogic 7.0, it just hasn't been removed for now (see the [FileT3](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/filet3.html) in Weblogic 8.1 documentation or [File T3](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/Corecoreserverserverservicesfilet3title.html) in Weblogic 10.0 documentation). If you need to write to the server file system, you'd better find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The T3 protocol is (was) a proprietary network protocol for Java object serialization and RMI (before there even was an official RMI). It was used to communicate within a cluster of WebLogic servers (and between servers and clients).

It is deprecated now, so unless you know what you need it for, you probably do not need it.

Comment: AFAIK, T3 is still proprietary and is still used by Weblogic.